# Как перемещать картинку в PictureBox, при этом прокручивая её по Y повторно?

Tags: c#

[Тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/7925a03c-028b-416c-b6d7-e67ab7c614f9/-picturebox-?forum=fordesktopru) нашел как перемещать картинку в PictureBox с помощью нажатой клавиши мышки. Но когда выхожу за пределы изображения, картинка обрывается и уходит за пределы экрана. Как можно переделать код, чтоб она прокручивалась по Y заново.  По X убрать возможность прокручивать дальше, когда выхожу за пределы картинки.

Comment: "прокручивалась бесконечно"??

Comment: Igor Чтоб она прорисовывалась, заново. Начиная с того места, где она начиналась, как в Google картах, когда мышкой перетаскиваешь по Y и выходишь за пределы карты, карты начинают повторятся. И да мне надо чтоб повторялось только по Y. По X надо убрать возможность   прокручивать дальше. Сейчас поправлю вопрос) Извиняюсь за неправильную постановку вопроса

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то Вам просто нужно отрисовывать Вашу картинку несколько раз, определяя смещение верхнего левого угла из нехитрых геометрических соображений - пересечения прямоугольников. Правда, гугловские карты (как и прочие тайл-мэпы) работают не так - там ничего повторяется, а грузятся новые растры, оказавшиеся внутри пользовательского вьюпорта.

Comment: Вам надо склеить 3 картинки. И прокручивать результат.

Comment: Leonid Malyshe , но мне не подойдёт такой вариант (склеить 3 картинки). Потому что эта картинка - карта . И на неё будут наноситься объекты. Если я склею три картинки в ряд, то я предполагаю, там будет две лишние области, в которых еще придётся дублировать  нанесённые объекты. Хотя можно разбить картинку на три картинки как вариант)....Спасибо за ответы буду пробовать)))